# General form of transformations $T:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In $\Bbb R^{n}$ we can write all linear transformations $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ as an $n\times n$ matrix. Is there any similar property for the space of matrices $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$? for example given $T: \mathbb{R}^{n\times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $X$ can we write $T(X) = AXB$ for some $A,B$?

Comment: Um, we could write them as an $(n\times m)\times (n\times m)$ matrix

Comment: I am asking about transformations of the vector space made up by $n\times m$ matrices, not vectors in $R^{nm}$, I will clarify the question

Comment: From the point of view of linear transformations, there is no difference between $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$ and $\mathbb R^{mn}$.

Comment: Are you asking about linear maps from the space of $n\times m$ matrices to itself? If so, that space, as a vector space, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ so as @RobertIsrael said there is no difference between the two from the point of view of linear transformations.

Comment: I understand that they are isomorphic as vector spaces so they have isomorphic endomorphism rings, I'm trying to find out if it's possible to write all the linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ in matrix form or if I have to move into $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$, apply the transformation there, and then move the result back into $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

Comment: Ultimately, the upshot of those (or any two) spaces being isomorphic is that one can freely move back and forth between the two spaces when doing computations. So yes, you can write linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ in terms of matrices, but they will be the same matrices you get from thinking of the space as $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$. This is a different way of saying what Robert said above, from the point of view of linear transformations (which, choice of basis nonwithstanding, are the same thing as matrices) there is no difference between the two spaces.

Comment: You could think of it as a $(2,2)$ tensor, e.g $$T^{ik}{}_{jl}A^l{}_k=B^i{}_j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $n m$ numbers to describe a linear transformation $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$.

Therefore, you need $(nm)^2$ numbers to describe a transformation $T$ from $n \times m$ matrices to $n \times m$ matrices.

If $f$ rearranges a $n \times m$ matrix to a $nm$-vector, then $T(X) = f^{-1} (A\cdot f(x))$, where $A$ is a $nm \times nm$ matrix.

I think you are asking if it's possible to write $T(X) = A X B$, as a matrix product, without going through $f$. This cannot work: $A$ and $B$ have $n^2 + m^2$ entries in total, less than the dimension $(nm)^2$. In fact, transformations of the form $A X B$ are not closed under addition.

Now, if you take finite sums $A_1 X B_1 + A_2 X B_2 + \dots A_n X B_n$, then it will work. If you take $T_{ijkl} = A_{ij} X B_{kl}$, where $A_{ij}$ is a matrix containing 1 at $(i,j)$ and 0 elsewhere, likewise for $B_{kl}$, that will be a basis, having the correct size $(nm)^2$. This is equivalent to using $f$ though.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Do you know of any results on approximating a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{nm\times nm}$ with $\sum^r_{i = 1} A_i \otimes B_i$? For example something bounding some norm of the difference based on $r$? Or any textbook recommendations?

Comment: I don't know the answer - you can ask a separate question.